# Is my OOP model of an entity correct?

Tags: java, xml, oop

I have an entity in XML form:

```
<Gun>
    <Model>FireBall</Model>
    <Handy>single-handled</Handy>
    <Origin>USA</Origin>
    <TTC>
        <Range>
            <Middle>543</Middle>
        </Range>
        <Catapulting>400</Catapulting>
        <IsMag>true</IsMag>
        <IsOptics>false</IsOptics>
        <Material>Steel</Material>
    </TTC>
</Gun>
```

And I've created a representation of this entity in a java class:

```
public class Gun {
    private String model;
    private String handy;
    private String origin;
    private int range;
    private int catapulting;
    private boolean isMag;
    private boolean isOptics;
    private String material;
}
```

In my opinion all the nested tags in XML are properties of Gun including the nested ones of TTC. But after all there's a question: maybe it'll be more correctly to create another class for TTC? I can't for sure answer it.

Comment: Neither solutions are wrong. Go with what works for you.

Comment: Created a class for TTC is more code.  Unless you *need* those properties bundled together, keep it simple :)

Comment: OOP is about communicating state machines, not hierarchical data modeling.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a second class for TTC. TTC needs to be declared as another entity if you wants to reach the [3rd normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). 3rd normal form is a best practices for data structure in relational databases, structured data files and NOSQL databases.

You should create a Ttc class and use it Gun class. There's not enough info in your message to know if you need a range class.

```
public class Gun {
    private String model;
    private String handy;
    private String origin;
    private Ttc ttc;
}
public class Ttc {
    private int range; // not enough info to know if you need a range class
    private int catapulting;
    private boolean isMag;
    private boolean isOptics;
    private String material;
}
```

Comment: Third-normal form is not an object-oriented notion and actually runs counter to good O-O analysis.

Comment: And there isn't enough info in the OP's message to know if he needs a TTC class either.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, the correct way to map the object model would have been -

```
public class Gun {
    private String model;
    private String handy;
    private String origin;
    private TTC ttc;
}
```

where `TTC` could be -

```
public class TTC {
    private Range range;
    private int catapulting;
    private boolean isMag;
    private boolean isOptics;
    private String material;
}
```

and `Range` can be further

```
public class Range {
    private int middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to decide which objects should exist is to list **responsibilities** your application needs to contain, and try to assign them to various objects.

In other words, you/we first need to know what those objects are supposed to **do**. A Gun should probably *fire*, or possible *damage* other objects, something like that.

Contrary to other paradigms, OO Design does not deal with data directly. It is not important (at least for the overall design) what data the individual objects contain, the only important thing is what functionality they are capable of being responsible for. Whether you need additional classes/objects (like TTC), will be decided by functionality and not by data.

So again, try to start with functionality. If you are able to model your domain well (and this may very well be difficult or take a long time or multiple iterations), the data will fit almost automatically.